If S*ti isn't a Hindu tradition, how do we explain Sati being mentioned in so many Hindu scriptures including Puranas and Dharmashastras?
There are numerous places in Hindu scriptures where it appears to be mentioned and even endorsed, but I've long been told that it was never a religiously ordained practice at all, and some have gone as far as saying that it isn't mentioned in Hinduism at all.
Dharmashastras
Parashar 4.28 - A widow, who immolates herself on the same funeral pile with her deceased husband, resides in heaven for ten millions of years, which is the number of hairs on the human body.
Daksha 4.19 - A woman, who, after the demise of her husband, ascends the funeral pyre, becomes of good conduct and lives gloriously in the celestial region.
Itihasas
Ramayan 2.66.12 - Kaushalya: "Today itself, I too in devotion to my husband, will meet my appointed end. I shall enter the fire, duly embracing this body of my husband."
Mahabharat 1.95.63 - 64 - And (one day) Pandu, beholding Madri decked with ornaments, had his desire kindled. And, as soon as he touched her, he died. Madri ascended the funeral pyre with her lord.
Mahabharat 1.126.30 - His wife Madri, beholding him placed in the funeral pyre and about to be consumed, herself ascended the same pyre, and sacrificing her life thus, hath gone with her lord to the region reserved for chaste wives.
Puranas
Kurma Purana 2.34.108 - 109 - A woman who enters the funeral pyre along with her husband, shall uplift him even if is a Brahmana-slayer, an ungrateful fellow or one defiled by great sins. learned men know this to be the greatest expiation for women.
Srimad Bhagavatam 9.9.36 - After this way cursing Mitrasaha [‘indulgent toward friends’ or Saudâsa] she, being devoted to be with her husband, found her destination by stepping into the fire that burned the bones of her husband.
Garuda Purana 1.107.29 - A Wife who dies in the company of her husband shall remain in heaven as many years as there are hairs on his person.
Garuda Purana 10.48 - The Woman who ascends the funeral pyre, when her husband is dead, becomes equal to Arundhati, and attains the heaven. [50] She who goes with her husband purifies three families her mother’s, her father’s, and that into which she was given.
Brahma Purana Gautami Mahatmya 10.75 - Dying Immediately after the husband is the greatest duty of women. This is the path laid down in the Vedas. [77] The woman who follows her husband shall stay in heaven for as many years as there are hairs in a man’s body, viz. three and a half crores of years.
Skanda Purana 3.1.12.115 - 116 - Ere long thereafter, King Manojava abandoned his body and went to the world of Siva, due to the power of that Tirtha. O Brahmanas, his wife Sumitra embraced his body then and ascended his funeral pyre. She too attained the same world.
Skanda Purana 3.2.7.53 - 56 - A *chaste woman who follows her husband from the house to the cremation ground for self-immolation undoubtedly attains the merit of a horse-sacrifice at every step.
Narada Purana, Uttarabhaga 30.87 - With a great deal of merits the woman goes to the region of Visnu alongwith her husband if her body is cremated alongwith him. But a woman greedy of wealth and of her body (?) attains Yama’s torture and the affliction of being born in base wombs of lower species.

I believe it was NOT must.. for example, in Ramayana, Kausalya just thought about it but didn’t commit Sati.. In MBH, Madri committed Sati but Kunti didn’t..

Who said it is not a hindu tradition. Only so called post modern reformist try to distance sati from Hinduism without understanding the rules of sati

Rig Veda does not support Sati and explicitly asks women not to do sati.

7 Let these unwidowed dames with noble husbands adorn themselves with
fragrant balm and unguent. Decked with fair jewels, tearless, free
from sorrow, first let the dames go up to where he lieth. 8 Rise, come
unto the world of life, O woman: come, he is lifeless by whose side
thou liest. Wifehood with this thy husband was thy portion, who took
thy hand and wooed thee as a lover.

Rig Veda 10.18.7-8
As far as I know there is no Hindu philosophy that supports Sati Pratha. There are some texts like the Puranas and Smritis (Parasara) that talk about voluntary Sati. The most precise philosophical argument against Sati Pratha has been given by the famous philosopher Medhatithi (c 825 ce).

कामं तु क्षपयेद् देहं पुष्पमूलफलैः शुभैः । न तु नामापि गृह्णीयात्
पत्यौ प्रेते परस्य तु ॥ १५५ ॥
kāmaṃ tu kṣapayed dehaṃ puṣpamūlaphalaiḥ śubhaiḥ | na tu nāmāpi
gṛhṇīyāt patyau prete parasya tu || 155 ||
Well might she macerate her body by means of pure flowers, roots and
fruits; but she should not even mention the name of another man, after
her husband is dead—(155).

Manu Smriti 5.155

What has been said in the preceding verse is explained more
specifically in the present verse.
As in the case of men, so in that of women also suicide is forbidden.
As for what Aṅgiras has said—‘they should die after their
husband’,—this also is not an obligatory act, and so it is not that it
must be done. Because in connection with it there is an eulogium
bestowed upon the results proceeding from such suicide. Thus then, the
performing of the act being possible only for one who is desirous of
obtaining the said result, the act stands on the same footing as the
Śyena sacrifice. That is, in connection with the Śyena sacrifice we
have the Vedic text—‘one may kill living beings by means of the Śyena
sacrifice,’—and this makes the performance of this sacrifice possible;
but only for one who has become blinded by extreme hatred; so that
when the man does perform the act, it does not become regarded as
‘Dharma,’ a ‘meritorious act’; exactly in the same manner, when the
widow happens to have a very strong desire for the results accruing
from the act of suicide, it is open to her to disobey the prohibition
of it and kill herself; but in so doing she cannot be regarded as
acting according to the scriptures. From this it is clear that the act
of killing herself after her husband is clearly forbidden for the
woman. Further, in view of the distinct Vedic text—‘one shall not die
before the span of his life is run out’—being contradicted by the
Smṛti-text of Aṅgiras, this latter is open to being assumed to have
some other meaning. Just as in the case of the Smṛti rule ‘one should
take the final bath after having read the Veda’,—the injunction of the
bath, as pertaining to one who has not yet studied the meaning of the
Vedic texts, has been taken as having a different meaning.

Medhatithi’s commentary of Manu Smriti
As far as I know no one has ever refuted Medhatithi’s criticism of the Sati Pratha.
There is another shloka in Manu Smriti that does not support Sati Pratha.

A virtuous wife who after the death of her husband constantly remains
chaste, reaches heaven, though she had no son, just like those chaste
men.

Manu Smriti 5.160
There is support for remarriage of widows
Woman’s second marriage

The five conditions or circumstances under which a woman is permitted
to marry again are: (1) the moral degradation of her husband, (2) his
death, (3) renunciation by him of all worldly pursuits, (4) his
resorting to a monastery, and (5) his impotency. The widow of a man
can marry the brother of his husband if living and willing to take her
as his wife, while in the alternative she may marry whomsoever she
pleases. ………

Agni Purana 154.5-7
In fact the pro-sati verses directly contradict the Vedas and are hence automatically invalid.
Why do some Smrti text ignore such writings?
The reason for this is that Hinduism has never had a centralized organization that enforces quality control. Just read the Gita verse posted below.

When your intellect, fed up with the bewildering scriptural doctrines
and their interpretations, settles (finally) in steady and unwavering
introspection (in the spirit), then you will attain to real Yoga.

Gita 2.53
A Hindu should do what he thinks is right and not blindly follow ancient texts. You might ask why instead of guidelines ancient Hindus didn’t throw out the discriminatory verses from these texts. There are at least two reasons for that. The first reason is that in the absence of printing press no text was safe from modification. A scholar copying a text can easily modify a text. The second reason is that Hinduism has no centralized organization to check errors in scriptures. Ancient Christians had the Church to select the texts that were considered to be correct and dump texts that did not reflect Christian teaching. Similarly one of the righteous Caliphs, companion of the Prophet, Uthman burnt down all variants of the Koran and commissioned a scholar to write the most authoritative version of it. Since Hindus do not have any such organization they have to look at scripture to see what it says about this issue. Hindu scriptures ask Hindus to do internal consistency checks before accepting any scriptural statement as valid. Hindu scriptural verse must survive three checks in order to be acceptable.
Reason

Even the words heard from an ignorant person, if in themselves they be
fraught with sense, come to be regarded as pious and wise. In days of
old, Usanas said unto the Daityas this truth, which should remove all
doubts, that scriptures are no scriptures if they cannot stand the
test of reason.

Mahabharata Shanti Parva Section CXLII
Acharya Shankara says:

The appeal to the infallibility of the Vedic injunction is
misconceived. The infallibility in question refers only to the unseen
forces or apurva, and is admissible only in regards to matters not
confined to the sphere of direct perceptions, etc ... Even a hundred
statements of sruti to the effect that fire is cold and non-luminous
won't prove valid. If it does make such a statement, its import will
have to be interpreted differently. Otherwise, validity won't attach
to it. Nothing in conflict with the means of valid cognition or with
its own statements may be imputed to sruti.

REF: Srimad Bhagavad Gita Bhasya 18.66 of Sri Sankaracarya translation by Dr. A. G. Krishna Warrier

yuktiyuktamupādeyaṃ vacanaṃ bālakādapi | anyattṛṇamiva tyājyamapyuktaṃ
padmajanmanā || 3 ||
The remark of a child is to be accepted, if it is in accordance with
reason; but the remark of even Brahma Himself, the creator of the
world is to be rejected like a piece of straw if it does not accord
with reason.

REF: Vasistha's Yoga translated by Swami Venkatesananda, p 35
Non-discrimination

If a holy act is against the interest of other members of the society,
it should not be practiced. It is Dharma which is the source of Artha
and even of Kama.

Kurma Purana I.2.54
If a scriptural verse does advocate discrimination (sati discriminates against women) then discard it.
Conscience


The whole Veda is the (first) source of the sacred law, next the tradition  and the virtuous conduct of those who know the (Veda
further), also the customs of holy men, and (finally)
self-satisfaction.


Manu Smriti II.6

Bhishma said, ‘He is said to be conversant with duty who knows duty as
depending on four foundations.’

[four foundations, i.e., as laid down in the Vedas; as laid down in the Smritis; as sanctioned by ancient usage and customs; and as approved by the heart or one’s own conscience.]
Mahabharata, Santi Parva, Section CXXXII
Hindu scripture can’t override reason and conscience. Nor can Hindu scripture be used to discriminate against a community.
The Smriti texts and the Puranas that we have today reflect the attitude of people who lived many centuries ago. Most of these texts have been revised many times. These texts teach us to adapt these teachings to modern times and in fact discard any teaching that seems obsolete today..

However, discard the desire (kama) and material wealth (artha) if
contrary to Dharma; as also, any usage or custom or rules regarded as
source of Dharma if at any time they were to lead to unhappiness or
arouse people's indignation.

(Manu Smriti 4.176)
What should we do with these pro-Sati verses?
A Hindu should only take the essential teachings and not be a fundamentalist. The pro-sati verses should be discarded. These verses may be in scripture but should not be treated as scripture.
Essential Teachings

An intelligent man should seek the essential teachings of all
scriptural texts of varying importance, just as a honey-bee sucks the
essence of all flowers.

Srimad Bhagavata Purana XI.8.10

Not being mandatory does not mean it is not supported
